# Jquery валидация формы в yii2

Tags: yii2

Отлавливаю submit и валидирую форму, дальше проверяю есть ли элементы с классом ".has-error". Если первый раз нажал и есть такие элементы, то код не видит их, а при повторном нажатии отлавливает их. Форма загружается в модальное окно по ajax. В чем трабл может быть?

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-modal-submit]', function () {
var loader = $('.container__loader--wrapper');
loader.show();
$('.btn-modal_close').prop('disabled', true);
$('[data-submit-form]').prop({'disabled': true});

var form = $($(this).data('modalSubmit'));
```

var data = form.serialize();

```
var activeForm = form.data('yiiActiveForm');

$.each(activeForm.attributes, function() {
    this.status = 3;
});

form.yiiActiveForm("validate");

if ($('div').is(".has-error")){
    $('.btn-modal_close').prop('disabled', false);
    $('[data-submit-form]').prop({'disabled': false});
    loader.hide();
    return false;
} else {
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function () {
            console.log($('div').is(".has-error"));
        },
        success: function (res) {
            if (res.status == true){
                var pjaxTable = form.attr('data-update-pjax');
                var updateContent = form.data('updateContent');
                if (typeof pjaxTable !== typeof undefined && pjaxTable !== false) {
                    $.pjax.reload({container: pjaxTable});
                }
                if (typeof updateContent !== typeof undefined && updateContent !== false) {
                    $(updateContent).html(res.content);
                }
                $('.modal').modal('hide');
                toastr.success(res.message, params.toastr());
            } if (res.status == false){
                toastr.error(res.message, params.toastr());
            }
            $('.btn-modal_close').prop('disabled', false);
            $('[data-submit-form]').prop({'disabled': false});
            loader.hide();
        }
    });
  }
});
```

Форма

```
<?php
   $form = ActiveForm::begin([
             'id' => 'contactPeopleForm',
              'options' => [
                 'data-content-update' => '.js-contact-person__all'
              ],
              'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
              'validationUrl' => Url::to(['/manager/client/contact-people/validation',
              'scenario' => $model->scenario])
             ])
 ?>
```

Comment: Добрый день. Потому, что неверно используете ajax валидацию в формах yii2. Покажите код формы.

Comment: Формы? или jquery?

Comment: А форма где? Вы используете pjax? Зачем тогда отдельно jquery? Вот, посмотрите, должно Вам помочь https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URhvUwebSvc

Comment: Нет, я не использую pjax!!! <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
            'id' => 'contactPeopleForm',
            'options' => [
                'data-content-update' => '.js-contact-person__all'
            ],
            'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
            'validationUrl' => Url::to(['/manager/client/contact-people/validation', 'scenario' => $model->scenario])
        ]) ?>

Comment: Посмотрите по ссылке, что я дал выше. И вот ещё одна полезная ссылка https://yii2-cookbook.readthedocs.io/forms-activeform-js/